# Scrollbar "Mouse scroll" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

How to capture scroll event on scrollbar (`overflow:scroll` div)?

If I do `$(selector).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {}` it captures **mouse scroll** but how to capture here **mouse clicked on scrollbar and moved** scroll event?

Putting it diffrently: how to caputre both mouse scroll and mouse click scroll events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scroll event http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

As stated in the docs

> A scroll event is sent whenever the element's scroll position changes,
>   regardless of the cause. A mouse click or drag on the scroll bar,
>   dragging inside the element, pressing the arrow keys, or using the
>   mouse's scroll wheel could cause this event.

Comment: Thats correct answer, however how would you group that http://pastebin.com/ky25zUkQ ?

Comment: @Ultra what exactly do you mean by group?